# Can't scrape from JS to c#

Tags: c#, javascript

There is a simple code that performs CRC32 check on JS. I'm scraping all the page and trying do spoof all the string. I have an issue calculating part of this function, especially `chlg` variable:

```
var c = 354939801
var slt = "zws0mUwF"
var s1 = 'h'
var s2 = 'l'
var n = 4
var start = s1.charCodeAt(0);
var end   = s2.charCodeAt(0);
var arr = new Array(n);
var m = Math.pow(((end - start) + 1),n);
for (var i=0; i<n; i++)
arr[i] = s1;
for (var i=0; i<m-1; i++)
{
    for(var j=n-1; j>=0;--j)
    {
        var t = arr[j].charCodeAt(0);
        t++;
        arr[j] = String.fromCharCode(t);
        if (arr[j].charCodeAt(0)<=end)
        {
            break;
        } 
        else
        {
            arr[j] = s1 ;
        }
    }
    var chlg = arr.join("");
}
```

I have written the analogue for c# for counting `chlg` variable

```
string chlg = "";
string cr = getBetween1(path1, "var c = ", " ").Substring(0,11);
string cr_cleaned = rxNonDigits1.Replace(cr, "");
int cr_int = Convert.ToInt32(cr_cleaned);
string slt = getBetween1(path1, "var slt = \"", "\"");
string s1_str = getBetween1(path1, "var s1 = '", "'");
char s1 = Convert.ToChar(s1_str);
string s2_str = getBetween1(path1, "var s2 = '", "'");
char s2 = Convert.ToChar(s2_str);
string n_pre = getBetween1(path1, "var n = ", "v").Substring(0, 1);
int n_int = Convert.ToInt32(n_pre);
double n = Convert.ToDouble(n_int);
double start = s1;
double end = s2;
int end_int = Convert.ToInt32(end);
double m = Math.Pow(((end - start)+1),n);
char[] arr;
arr = new char[n_int];
for (var i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
     arr[i] = s1;
}
for (int i = 0; i < m - 1; i++)
{
     for (int j = n_int - 1; j >= 0; --j)
     {
          int t = arr[j]; 
          t++; 
          arr[j] = Convert.ToChar(t); 
          if (t <= end_int)
          {
              break;
          }
          else
          {
              arr[j] = s1;
          }
     }
     chlg = string.Join("", arr);
}
```

For `s1 = 'h'` and `s2 = 'l'` I'm always getting `'llll'`, when JS code is getting `'hkkm'`, `'mkkl'` etc.
Why it's happening? Why JS always calculating this randomly?

Answer (score 0):

That javascript you have always assigned 'hhhi' to chlg.  If you are wanting the equivalent in c#, here's a conversion for you:

```
public void Challenge()
    {
        var c = 354939801;
        var slt = "zws0mUwF";
        var s1 = 'h';
        var s2 = 'l';
        var n = 4;
        var start = (int)s1;
        var end = (int)s2;
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        var m = Math.Pow((start - end) + 1, n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(s1);
        }
        var str = sb.ToString().ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < (m - 1); i++)
        {
            for (int j = n - 1; j >= 0; --j)
            {
                var t = (int)str[j];
                t++;
                str[j] = (char)t;
                if ((int)str[j] <= (int)end)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    str[j] = s1;
                }
            }
            var chlg = str.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Just so you know, in C#, you can cast a char as an int and vice-versa.  I feel like your javascript isn't complete since it just assigns a value, so if you are testing a larger function, you might want to break it down while converting it and get smaller chunks working one at a time.